# Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory is not working with Webhook

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-data-factory

I am using azure datafactory WebHook to get detial of Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory using following link.
POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/queryPipelineRuns?api-version=2018-06-01)
I filled up all the required variable eg subcriptionId etc i works on postman using my credentials. but i need to run this using MSI and from datafactory (currently using webhook).

Using MSI authentication. my datafactory have owner role.
[image]

Then made a post request from datafactory using webhook. tried both option by selecting callback and without call back.
[image]

When i run that its take long time (10 min ) and status shows that its timeout.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi after spending much time to fix it i found that MSI authentication is not available in WebHook. Instead Web will do that business.
So web Activity is the right guy.